# Dynamics Crm records bulk edit

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

When I want to "bulk" edit a few records of a custom entity, I select them in the view and a form opens. There is a section that is missing in this form. How can I control the sections and fields that appear in this bulk edit form?

Comment: Is the section visible in form customization ?

Comment: @Alex: yes, but I think that I don't see it in the bulk edit form only because it is not visible by default, and then set visible with javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the section is customized to be Visible, if it's hidden and shown via Javascript it's not going to show up.

Answer (score 0):

The "bulk edit" form contains all the fields and sections contained in the main form, except the ones that are not visible by default.

In my case the section is not visible by default, and it is set visible in javascript if some conditions are met. I set it to visible by default, and changed the javascript, in this way the section appears in the bulk edit form.